acf wordpress: i am trying o display images choosed by checkbox by administrator
i am trying to create a function in php that will display the right images. using plugin ACF
i was expecting: enable the admin to select images on the product edit page using ACF and then display the selected images on the product page.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wtwh_acf_custom_product_field',15 );
function wtwh_acf_custom_product_field() { ?>
 
<?php if(get_field('structure_finish')) { ?>
    <div class="cg-customcss"><?php the_field('structure_finish'); ?></div>
<?php }
    
    if(get_field('top_finish')) { ?>
    <div class="cg-customcss1"><?php the_field('top_finish'); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
<br/>
<?php
$structure = get_field('structure_finish');                                       
$image1 = get_field('image1');
$image2 = get_field('image2');
$image3 = get_field('image3');
$image4 = get_field('image4');
$image5 = get_field('image5');
$image6 = get_field('image6');
for (x of $structure){
if(x == $image1 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image1['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image1['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
if(x == $image2 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image2['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image2['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
if(x == $image3 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image3['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image3['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
if(x == $image4 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image4['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image4['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
if(x == $image5 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image5['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image5['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
if(x == $image6 ): ?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($image6['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image6['alt']); ?>" />
<?php endif;  
}
                                          
}


for (x of $structure) is not valid PHP syntax, are you looking for foreach or is this pseudo code? Same with if(x == $image6 )

The repetitive code begs for a loop from 1 to 6, too
